# Import .jpg texture into Blender

Tags: texturing

I have a cityscape 3d model that is in .obj format. When I import it into Blender, it does not import the .jpg texture files. Is there any way that I can import the textures manually? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to convert the .obj file in a different format.

To load images as textures I used that plugin:
https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh/Planes_from_Images

Comment: How would I then apply the image to the mesh? @user3054986

Comment: Can you publish your obj file?